# Why does this equation for Bayesian probability work?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Please refer to question 4 and its answer at this link: https://risingentropy.com/some-simple-probability-puzzles/ How does what is referred to as strength of evidence relate to the Bayes equation.  In particular, how can you calculate the probability without assuming a prior probability?

Comment: The *somewhat unrealistic* problem **is** solvable because the information that is needed is contained in the statements : "If the patient has strep throat, the lab results are right 70% of the time. If not, then the lab is right 90% of the time."  Assume that the patient has Strep Throat: Then, based on the information given, what are the chances of getting 2-Y's and 3-N's.  Now, make the alternate assumption, that the patient does not have Strep Throat.  Again, compute the chances of 2-Y's and 3-N's.  Now compare the two computations against each other.  This is classic Bayes Theorem.

Comment: Someone, using the same id, chose to duplicate this query at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3866739/why-does-this-equation-work-in-computing-bayesian-probability-see-details

Comment: A classic example of the harm in abusing downvoting, as discussed at : https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: There are not two equations.  There is just one, and it is not the same as P(A|B)= P(B|A)P(A)/P(B).  I computed the probability by using a prior probability of 50% and updating P(A) for each result using the Bayes Equation.  I got the same answer to 14 places as 49/76.. If I use a prior different from 50%, I get a different answer   Somehow a prior of 50% is being assumed.

Comment: Interesting.  Part of the communication problem was that I was not allowed to give an answer until you showed work.  Although it would have been better if you had placed the analysis in your comment directly into your query, as far as I am concerned, you **have** now shown work.  I will amplify my comment in an answer.  Then, I **invite** you to leave a comment directly below my answer, if you disagree in any way.  By doing it that, I will automatically be flagged.

Comment: For those of you who are wondering about my previous comments, I just upvoted, because the OP's last comment shows work.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an amplification of my original comment to this query.

You are given that :

If the patient has strep throat, the lab results are right 70% of the time.

If not, then the lab is right 90% of the time.

5 Lab tests were performed, resulting in 2-Y's and 3-N's 
where "Y" denotes strep throat test is positive.

In this unrealistic problem, based on the above information, you are **guaranteed**
that one of two things has occurred.

Event-1
Either the patient **does** have strep throat, and the results were 2-Y's and 3-N's.

Event-2
Or the patient **does** not have strep throat, and the results were 2-Y's and 3-N's.

Regardless of the (unspecified) normal probability that someone has Strep Throat, the question is: In the **absence** of any information other than that given in the problem, what are the relative probabilities of Event-1 vs Event-2.

The chance of Event-1 occurring, in the absence of any other information, is

$A = (.7)^2 \times (.3)^3.$

The chance of Event-2 occurring, in the absence of any other information, is

$B = (.1)^2 \times (.9)^3.$

Therefore, since you are guaranteed that either Event-1 or Event-2 occurred,

the chance that Event-1 occurred is $\frac{A}{A + B}$

and the chance that Event-2 occurred is $\frac{B}{A + B}.$

I can't resist this: 
One way of making sense of this is to pretend that you are living in a **bizarro** world, where an unknown disease is of unknown origin, and all deductions re the likelihood of someone having this unknown disease will be based on the empirical results of semi-mentally-retarded testers.

**Addendum**

Another way of interpreting the problem is that

There is a multiple choice question with two possible answers, A and B.

Person-1 Chose choice A and Person-2 chose choice B.

The question was then graded 5 different times, by 5 different teachers,
each acting independently.

It is given that when Person-1 answers a question correctly, 
the probability of a teacher grading the question correctly is .7.

When Person-2 answers a question correctly, 
the probability of a teacher grading the question correctly is .9.

Given that 2 teachers graded Person-1's answer as correct, 
and 3 teachers graded Person-2's answer is correct, 
what are the chances that Person-1's answer of "A" is correct?

Comment: I see what you did, and even see how what was done assumes a prior of 50% for both A and B.  What I am having trouble with is seeing why updating p(A) after 5 tests is equivalent to updating P(A) after each test, which is what I did.  Logically it makes sense, but I do not see how the algebra works out.

Comment: @user1153980 Where you and I disagree, is that you are assuming "a prior of 50% for both A and B". You are not allowed to make that assumption. You are (instead) required to presume that you have no information about the relative probability of A vs B, other than what you can deduce, based on the information given in the problem.  See also the editing that I just inserted, right before my Addendum.

Comment: The 50% is implicit.  Given that a strep throat occurs 50% of the time the probability of event 1 is .5(.7)^2(.3)^3 and similarly for event 2.  The .5 terms cancel when computing A/B. The article talks about getting different answers by varying the priors.

Like I said, what I am having trouble with is seeing why updating P(strep throat) after 5 tests gives the same answer as updating P(strep throat) after each test. Intuitively, it seems that updating after each test should be more accurate.

Comment: @user1153980 In the remark that I inserted into my answer, just before the Addendum, in the bizarro world, would the chance of someone having an unknown disease of unknown origin implicitly be 50%, or would the chance be **unknown**?  We may have to agree to disagree on what may ultimately be an interpretation issue.

Comment: I really would like to know why updating the probability after 5 tests is the same as updating the probability one test at a time.  It seems as if updating one test at a time should be more accurate, but the answer turned out to be the same either way.  I may post a separate question for this.

Comment: @user1153980 I don't know what you intend by "updating the probability one test at a time".  It seems like that approach requires an initial assumption, like absent any other info, chance of Strep Throat = 50%.  However, that approach is forbidden?  Have I mis-interpreted you?  Do you have a different approach in mind, that accepts my premise that you can't start with the idea that p(Strep Throat) = 1/2 (or anything)?  Please edit your query to provide details, and send me a message, and I'll look at it.

Comment: Using Bayes equation always requires an initial probability assignment. P(B|A) = P(B|A)P(A)/P(B).  You need an initial value of P(A). What I meant by doing one test at a time is to compute P(B|A) for the first result, set P(A) to that new value and update based on the second result, and continue for each of the remaining results.  It must be equivalent to combining all the results, because I get the same answer either way, but I don't see why.

Comment: @user1153980 Now, I see what you are saying (perhaps I was too narrow minded to see it before).  So when I said that this was classic Bayes Theorem, I intended that on an **intuitive** rather than **formal** level.  Yes, I agree, formal Bayes Theorem is unworkable here, because of my insistence that $p(A)$ be *undefined*.  However, intuitively, Bayes Theorem type problems usually result in a *scenario* that resembles the following: ...see next comment.

Comment: @user1153980  You have 4 mutually exclusive possible events, $R, S, T, U$, with $p(R) + p(S) + p(T) + p(U) = 1.$  You are given that events $T$ and $U$ did **not** occur, and are asked to calculate the probability that event $R$ occurred, **given** that events $T$ and $U$ did not occur.  Then the chances that event $R$ occurred is $\frac{p(R)}{p(R) + p(S)}.$  This scenario parallels the scenario in the problem.

Comment: Like I said previously, not assigning an initial value to P(A) is equivalent to an assumption of 50%.  The article later gives an example of what happens if an initial value is assumed.

Comment: @user1153980 what article, I'd like to read it?  Is it available online?  If not, can you use mathJax to add an Addendum to your query, (indicating that you are adding the Addendum at my request) and place the analysis from the article directly into your query.  Then, (either way), once I have something **tangible** to examine, we can discuss it.

Comment: @user1153980 It occurs to me that your reference to "an article" is referring to the article linked in your original posting.  If so, that article's analysis of the problem (problem 4 in the article) is **dead wrong**.  The article claims for example that "Each YES provides evidence with strength 7:1 (70%/10%) in favor of strep, and each NO provides evidence with strength 1:3 (30%/90%)."  I'm sorry, you can't figure it that way.  The way that my answer computed it is the only way that makes sense.

Comment: Do you get an answer that is different from the one in the article?  It says that the probability is A/(A+B)=49/76.

Comment: The computation that I get, as shown in my answer, **exactly matches** 49/76.  It is just that their explanation of how to perform the computation is **off-the-wall** bad.  The *explanation* that I gave is *sensible*.

Comment: Their method is also different from the way I did it, which is why I posted this question in the first place.  It was based on what you said that I could understand the rationale  for the method in the article.  The question then is, why does the article's method give the correct answer?  Was it just a coincidence (which seems unlikely) or is there an algebraic justification?

Comment: @user1153980 It is **not** a coincidence.  Their method is essentially the same as mine algebraically.  It is just that they used totally non-standard and off-the-wall ideas after the fact to justify their approach.  Algebraically, their approach is **valid but retarded**.  You have to be very sophisticated to even understand why their approach is valid.  The answer that I gave you uses the method that virtually all mathematicians use.  Further, the method that I gave **makes sense.**